# Trying to install Pharo Smalltalk on Debian testing (stretch)

Tags: debian, smalltalk, pharo

While trying to install Pharo 4 on Debian testing on a 64-bit machine, I ran into some frustrating issues where some dependencies are not met, and the required libraries are not documented anywhere. In particular vm-display-X11 is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out after a lot of false starts and silly frustration that I needed to install the 32-bit versions of some libraries. I ended up needing these:
libfreetype6:i386
libssl1.0.0:i386
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
libx11-6:i386

This was for my setup in particular and I found out which ones were needed by running `ldd <library>` for every library in the directory. I thought I would see if I could save future frustrated googlers a bit of time.

Comment: Thanks. We are aware of these issues and are trying to improve.